# Why i can't set begin value of animate element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, svg-animate

Why I can't set begin value of animate element using javascript?

as you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/z69fL3wk/ , the starting color of gradient  animation is blue because `begin` value was set from HTML code with -30s.

but when I try to set `begin` value using JavaScript here https://jsfiddle.net/h70j21m4/ , it didn't show the same result.

I use this jQuery to set it:

```
$("animate").attr("begin", "-30s");
```

This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCZA9.jpg) is taken from inspect element the second link (the one that using javascript to set `begin` value). It shows the same HTML code as the first link (the one that directly set `begin` value from HTML code) but the result is different.

Any other javascript method that produce blue as starting gradient animation color (set the time has passed by 30s) beside using `setCurrentTime()` method ?

Note : I successfully set `dur` value here https://jsfiddle.net/30gkec7z/ using the same method (`attr()`)

Comment: Try using something like `let animate = document.querySelectorAll("animate")
animate.forEach(a=>{a.beginElementAt(-30)})`

Comment: @enxaneta It didn't work. It's said "a.beginElementAt is not a function".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by set `begin` value with `indefinite` at HTML code, then set it with javascript.
https://jsfiddle.net/oqh24kfs/